# What cause this weird bug in my selfplaying tetris written in Python 3?

Tags: python, bots, tetris

What happen is that at certain point when a piece is put to its place suddenly the a whole column became solid. Putting breakpoint on line 236 one can debug this and see that in the value assignment:

```
gameSpace[current_y + x][current_x + y] = current_piece + 1
```

Suddenly not just one field of the `gameSpace` is changing, but a whole column and its just does not make sense for me. (I'm extremely beginner in Python, written my tetris originally in C on an MCU board and now trying to port to PC to be able find the best parameters for the fitness function.) The indices into the 2D game space are also valid so that could not cause it.

[image: tetris bug]

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import seed
from random import randint
import time

# seed random number generator
seed(1)

# constants
PX_WIDTH = 480
PX_HEIGHT = 640
BLOCK_SIZE = PX_HEIGHT / 20
HEIGHT = int(PX_HEIGHT / BLOCK_SIZE)
WIDTH = int(HEIGHT / 2)
TICK_CNT = 1

current_piece = randint(0, 6)
current_x = 3
current_y = 0
current_rotation = 0

scores = 0

ticks = 0

colors = ["black", "blue", "orange", "green", "yellow", "red", "purple", "brown"]

gameSpaceBOT = [0] * HEIGHT
for i in range(HEIGHT):
    gameSpaceBOT[i] = [0] * WIDTH

tetrominos = [
    [[0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]]
]

def rotatedIndex(rotation, index):
    if rotation == 0:
        return index
    if rotation == 1:
        # 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15
        # 12 8  4  0  13 9  5  1  14 10 6   2   15  11  7   3
        return int(12 - ((index % 4) * 4) + int(index / 4))
    if rotation == 2:
        return 15 - index
    if rotation == 3:
        # 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15
        # 3  7  11 15 2  6  10 14 1  5  9   13  0   4   8   12
        return int(15 - int(index / 4) - ((3 - (index % 4)) * 4))

def doesItFit(piece, rota, in_x, in_y, gameSpace):
    piece_x = in_y
    piece_y = in_x
    idx = 0

    for x in range(4):
        for y in range(4):
            idx = rotatedIndex(rota, x * 4 + y)
            gs_x = piece_x + x
            gs_y = piece_y + y
            if tetrominos[piece][int(idx / 4)][idx % 4] != 0:
                if gs_x >= 0 and gs_x < HEIGHT and gs_y >= 0 and gs_y < WIDTH:
                    if gameSpace[gs_x][gs_y] != 0:
                        return 0
                else:
                    return 0
    return 1

# print for debug
def printGamespace(gameSpace):
    for x in range(HEIGHT):
        for y in range(WIDTH):
            print(gameSpace[x][y], end=" ")
        print()

# drawing the gamespace
def drawGamespace(C, squares_list, gameSpace):
    ### print("in drawGamespace")
    #gameSpace[randint(0, HEIGHT-1)][randint(0, WIDTH-1)] = 1
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        for x in range(WIDTH):
            C.itemconfig(squares_list[y * WIDTH + x], fill=colors[gameSpace[y][x]])

    #draw current piece
    for x in range(4):
        for y in range(4):
            idx = rotatedIndex(current_rotation, x * 4 + y)
            if tetrominos[current_piece][int(idx / 4)][idx % 4] != 0:
                C.itemconfig(squares_list[(current_y + x) * WIDTH + (current_x + y)], fill="white")

def spawnNewPiece(gameSpace):
    ### print("in spawnNewPiece")
    global current_x
    current_x = 3
    global current_y
    current_y = 0
    global current_rotation
    current_rotation = randint(0, 3)
    global current_piece
    current_piece = randint(0, 6)

    return doesItFit(current_piece, current_rotation, current_x, current_y, gameSpace)

def calculateFitness(gameSpace):
    lineFillednessFactor = 0
    lineSolved = 0

    for x in range(HEIGHT):
        currentRowFilledness = 0
        for y in range(WIDTH):
            if gameSpace[x][y] != 0:
                currentRowFilledness = currentRowFilledness + 1
        if currentRowFilledness == WIDTH:
            lineSolved += 1
        lineFillednessFactor += currentRowFilledness * (x + 1)
    return lineFillednessFactor + 10000 * lineSolved

def bot(gameSpace):
    global gameSpaceBOT
    global current_rotation
    global current_x
    local_y = current_y
    target_x = current_x
    target_rot = current_rotation
    bestFitness = -1

    for x in range(HEIGHT):
        for y in range(WIDTH):
            gameSpaceBOT[x][y] = gameSpace[x][y]

    for rot in range(4):
        for x in range(WIDTH + 3):
            if doesItFit(current_piece, rot, x - 3 , local_y, gameSpace) == 1:
                # moving down until it stucks
                while doesItFit(current_piece, rot, x - 3 , local_y + 1, gameSpace) == 1:
                    local_y = local_y + 1
                # fitting the piece into the BOTs gameSpace
                for px in range(4):
                    for py in range(4):
                        idx = rotatedIndex(rot, px * 4 + py)
                        if tetrominos[current_piece][int(idx / 4)][idx % 4] == 1:
                            gameSpaceBOT[local_y + px][x - 3 + py] = current_piece + 1
                # if the resulting gamespace fitness is better then the current best one
                # then change the target coordinates for the best solution to the current one
                if calculateFitness(gameSpaceBOT) > bestFitness:
                    bestFitness = calculateFitness(gameSpaceBOT)
                    target_x = x - 3
                    target_rot = rot
                # removing the piece for the next iteration
                for px in range(4):
                    for py in range(4):
                        idx = rotatedIndex(rot, px * 4 + py)
                        if tetrominos[current_piece][int(idx / 4)][idx % 4] == 1:
                            gameSpaceBOT[local_y + px][x - 3 + py] = 0
    # depending on our current position move the current piece towards the target
    # first do the rotation
    ### print('target_rot={:d}, target_x={:d}'.format(target_rot, target_x))
    if target_rot != current_rotation:
        if target_rot > current_rotation:
            current_rotation = current_rotation + 1
        else:
            current_rotation = current_rotation - 1
    # if rotation is correct than move it horrizontally
    elif target_x != current_x:
        if target_x > current_x:
            current_x = current_x + 1
        else:
            current_x = current_x - 1

def checkAndRemoveFilledLines(gameSpace):
    global scores
    first_found_line_y_coord = 0
    found_lines = 0
    for x in range(HEIGHT):
        num_of_blocks_in_row = 0
        for y in range(WIDTH):
            if gameSpace[x][y] != 0:
                num_of_blocks_in_row = num_of_blocks_in_row + 1
        if num_of_blocks_in_row == WIDTH:
            found_lines = found_lines + 1
            if first_found_line_y_coord == 0:
                first_found_line_y_coord = x
    # if there was filled lines then add to score and erase the lines
    if found_lines != 0:
        scores += 10
        for x in range(first_found_line_y_coord + found_lines - 1, 0, -1):
            ### print("x is {:d}".format(x))
            gameSpace[x] = gameSpace[x - found_lines]

def update(C, squares_list, gameSpace):
    global ticks
    ticks = (ticks + 1) % TICK_CNT
    global current_y
    global scores

    bot(gameSpace)

    if ticks == 0:
        # if it able to move down than move it down
        if doesItFit(current_piece, current_rotation, current_x, current_y + 1, gameSpace) == 1:
            current_y = current_y + 1
        else:
            if current_y == 8 and current_piece == 5 and current_x == 5:
                print("hey")
            scores += 1
            for x in range(4):
                for y in range(4):
                    idx = rotatedIndex(current_rotation, x * 4 + y)
                    if tetrominos[current_piece][int(idx / 4)][idx % 4] != 0:
                        gameSpace[current_y + x][current_x + y] = current_piece + 1
            checkAndRemoveFilledLines(gameSpace)
            if not spawnNewPiece(gameSpace):
                return 0
    drawGamespace(C, squares_list, gameSpace)
    C.after(1, update, C, squares_list, gameSpace)

def main():
    # canvasd
    root = Tk()
    C = Canvas(root, bg="black", height=PX_HEIGHT, width=PX_WIDTH)
    C.pack()

    # for storing the rectangles
    squares_list = []

    # init
    # creating and initializing the game space 2d array
    gameSpace = [0] * HEIGHT
    for i in range(HEIGHT):
        gameSpace[i] = [0] * WIDTH

    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        for x in range(WIDTH):
            squares_list.append(C.create_rectangle(x * BLOCK_SIZE,
                                y * BLOCK_SIZE,
                                (x + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE,
                                (y + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE,
                                fill=colors[gameSpace[y][x]]))

    update(C, squares_list, gameSpace)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You are mixing `x` and `y`, like here `gameSpace[current_y + x][current_x + y]` but that's not the reason. Here you copy a reference instead of values: `gameSpace[x] = gameSpace[x - found_lines]`, change to `gameSpace[x] = deepcopy(gameSpace[x - found_lines])`. Furthermore reconsider: `for x in range(WIDTH + 3):` and the usage of `gameSpace` instead of `gameSpaceBOT` within `def bot(...`

Comment: You are right, the deepcopy fixed it. There were another issue somewhat related to this line. The range `for x in range(first_found_line_y_coord + found_lines - 1, 0, -1):`. The 0 should be `found_lines` otherwise bad things happen. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out by stovfl the problem was indeed that the gameSpace was copied by reference and not by value. Using `deepcopy` solved it.

Comment: That guilty pleasure when even you had faced troubles in debugging lol

Comment: @ArdentCoder Yepp time to time you just get lost in your code you know.